# Can MQIPT be configured to authenticate the credentials set by MQ client for a specific connection

Tags: ibm-mq

Scenario: MQIPT is used in between a MQ client and MQ server version 8.

Is it possible to  validate the credentials sent along with the channel connection at MQIPT. I checked the documentation and it seems it cannot be done unless some kind of security exit is written for it.

Just wanted to get views on this, as to how it can be achived if at all possible.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are talking about username password validation at MQIPT your assessment is correct, it can not do this.  You could have the client use a certificate and have MQIPT match the cert based on the cert DN and signer DN.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the cert configurations as you specified.

Comment: @JoshMc, do you know if we can read the user/password in the security exit at MQIPT. My findings: MQIPT uses SecurityExit/CertificateExit class to initiate the validation process, allowing only handful of connection information available like channel name, QM name, Client IP, port etc. But coulnt get anything which can be used to read the user/password details

Comment: If you found the information I provided in my answer useful please accept it by clicking the grayed out check mark directly under the down arrow to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MQIPT `com.ibm.mq.ipt.exit.SecurityExit` and `com.ibm.mq.ipt.exit.CertificateExit` classes do not expose the username and password information for a client channel.  Below is the documentation from IBM on these two types of exits.

[The com.ibm.mq.ipt.exit.SecurityExit class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ipt.doc/ipt2350_.htm) is documented in the IBM v9.0 Knowledge center with the following information:

> **public SecurityExitResponse validate(IPTTrace)**
>   The following properties are available:
>
> - listener port
> - destination
> - destination port
> - timeout
> - client IP address
> - client port address
> - channel name
> - queue manager name
>
> The validate method will be called by MQIPT when it receives a
>   connection request to validate. The channel name and queue manager
>   name will not be available if the SSLProxyMode property has been
>   enabled, as this feature is only used to tunnel SSL/TLS data and
>   therefore the data usually obtained from the initial data flow will be
>   unreadable.

[The com.ibm.mq.ipt.exit.CertificateExit class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ipt.doc/ipt2130_.htm) is is documented in the IBM v9.0 Knowledge center with the following information:

> Supported methods for obtaining properties:
>   **public int getListenerPort()**
>
> retrieves the route listener port - as defined by the ListenerPort
>   property
>
> **public String getDestination()**
>
> retrieves the destination address - as defined by the Destination
>   property
>
> **public int getDestinationPort()**
>
> retrieves the destination listener port address - as defined by the 
>   DestinationPort property
>
> **public String getClientIPAddress()**
>
> retrieves the IP address of the client making the connection request
>
> **public int getClientPortAddress()**
>
> retrieves the port address used by the client making the connection
>   request
>
> **public boolean isSSLClient()**
>
> used to determine if the exit is being called as an SSL/TLS client or
>   SSL/TLS server. If this returns true, the exit is on the client side
>   of the connection, validating the certificate obtained from the
>   server. If this returns false, the exit is on the server side of the
>   connection, validating the certificate sent by the client. It is valid
>   for a route to act as both an SSL/TLS server and an SSL/TLS client,
>   decrypting and re-encrypting traffic. In this situation, although
>   there is a single exit class, some instances of the class will be
>   called as clients and some as servers. You can use isSSLClient to
>   determine the situation for a given instance.
>
> **public int getConnThreadID()**
>
> used to retrieve the ID of the worker thread that is handling the
>   connection request, which can be useful for debugging.
>
> **public String getChannelName()**
>
> retrieves the IBM® MQ channel name that is used in the connection
>   request. This is available only when the incoming request is not using
>   SSL/TLS and MQIPT is acting as an SSL/TLS client.
>
> **public String getQMName()**
>
> retrieves the name of the IBM MQ queue manager used in the connection
>   request. This is available only when the client request is not using
>   SSL/TLS and MQIPT is acting as an SSL/TLS client.
>
> **public boolean getTimedout()**
>
> used by the exit to determine if the timeout has expired.
>
> **public IPTCertificate getCertificate()**
>
> retrieves the SSL/TLS certificate that needs to be validated.
>
> **public String getExitData()**
>
> retrieves the exit data, as defined by the SSLExitData property.
>
> **public String getExitName()**
>
> retrieves the exit name, as defined by the SSLExitName property.